# Why env variables are not evaluated in maven pom.xml repositories tag?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to make my project use private maven repository but encountered a problem with using env variables. If i use env variable like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>artifacts-write-repo</id>
        <url>${env.MAVEN_ARTIFACTS_WRITE_REPO_URL}</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

everything is ok and artifacts are deployed. But if I want to read artifacts with repositories tag:

```
<reposiories>
    <repository>
        <id>artifacts-read-repo</id>
        <url>${env.MAVEN_ARTIFACTS_READ_REPO_URL}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

env variable isn't evaluated. Why? And how can I resolve it?

Comment: You can use properties instead of environment variables which can be given via `.mvn/maven.config` ? like `mvn -DdistributionRelease=XXX` etc.

Comment: I resolved it declaring profile with repository in `settings.xml` but still don't know why not work with repository declaration

Comment: Because they are not supported at the moment simply...

Comment: @MariuszMączkowski see here as to why https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813598