# Maven property substitution for repository url not happening if parent pom is defined

Tags: java, maven

I'm having an issue where maven is not properly substituting properties into my repository URLs if and only if there is a parent pom defined. This is particularly a problem because the parent pom is IN the remote repository, so I need to have the parent pom defined.

minimum reproducible example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>project</name>
  <description>test project</description>

  <properties>
    <nexus.url>https://nexus.myorganization.net</nexus.url>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus-server</id>
      <url>${nexus.url}/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

Using this pom, I get the error message `Cannot access ${nexus.url}/repository/maven-snapshots/...` so clearly it is not replacing the property with the actual value.

If I remove the `<parent>` section of the POM, then suddenly property substitution begins working just fine:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>project</name>
  <description>test project</description>

  <properties>
    <nexus.url>https://nexus.myorganization.net</nexus.url>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus-server</id>
      <url>${nexus.url}/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <!-- adding this dependency so that Maven is forced to download from the repository -->
  <dependencies>
    <!-- some dependency here -->
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I know its working properly because I can see in maven's output the line `Downloading from nexus-server: https://nexus.myorganization.net/repository/maven-releases/...`

Any ideas?

Comment: Variable substitution is not available there. This is by design to make your builds more robust.

Comment: Why not? Why is it available only if there is no parent pom defined?

Comment: Repositories to consume from the only location should be your `settings.xml` file and should not be changed and should never being put into pom files...

Comment: I assume the error happens when parent pom is being downloaded from the repo? That would make sense because to build the whole list of properties you'd need to download the parent and build an Effective POM. So you can't apply properties because parent hasn't been downloaded and you can't download parent because properties haven't been applied. That's my take on why it doesn't work, but I didn't run any experiments to confirm the hypothesis.

Comment: It is trying to download the parent pom when it fails, so your hypothesis that property resolution does not happen until after the parent is downloaded is certainly a possibility.

Comment: It is available _AFTER_ the parent pom coordinates has been resolved.  You just can't do this.

Comment: This answer links to two related Maven tickets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36114683

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters, the reason is because the property resolution does not occur until after the parent pom has been resolved, so that there are no property conflicts between current pom and parent pom.

More details provided at tickets [MNG-2569](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2569) and [MNG-624](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-624) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36114683/774513)).

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a wrong tag in the definition of the parent.
Why is there a relativePath tag?

just remove the tag:  
and try it again

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a relative path tag, to be honest, but removing the tag does not change the behavior.

Comment: relativePath tells Maven where to look on disk relative to this pom.xml for the parent pom.  Typically the value is "directory above this"